Translation json files not found when deploying project to vercel
I am using next-intl package to localize my next app. On localhost, everything works as it is supposed to, but when I deploy the app to vercel, it seems that app cannot find the json files.
The build itself doesnt throw any error, but In console there is this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_next/data/XoP-CXuDxDooprFNUoha3/cs.json

So it seems that vercel cannot find json files with translations. The json files are stored in messages folder that is on root.
This is my i18n configuration:
export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
  if (!locales.includes(locale)) notFound();
  return {
    messages: (await import(`../../../messages/${locale}.json`)).default,
  };
});

My middleware:
export default createMiddleware({
  locales,
  defaultLocale,
  localePrefix,
  pathnames,
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/', '/(cs|en)/:path*'],
};

next.config.mjs:
const withNextIntl = createNextIntlPlugin(
  './src/business-web-core/src/i18n.ts',
);

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

export default withNextIntl(nextConfig);

And navigation:
export const { Link, getPathname, redirect, usePathname, useRouter } = createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation({
  locales,
  pathnames,
  localePrefix,
});

Thank you in advance.
